# Extracting values to fit into changing equations

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Not sure how to approach this situation. The best way to explain it might be visually, below is the diluted situation of what I have at hand:

Sheet 1:

```
Column A    Column B
Chocolate   20
Vanilla     10
Strawberry  30
```

Sheet 2:

```
Column A                            
Chocolate + Vanilla
Vanilla / Strawberry
Chocolate / (Strawberry + Vanilla)
```

Goal:

Sheet 2:

```
Column A                             Column B
Chocolate + Vanilla                  30
Vanilla / Strawberry                 1/3
Chocolate / (Strawberry + Vanilla)   1/2
```

The trouble I'm having is, I could do an index/match or vlookup approach and pull the numbers corresponding to the flavors (chocolate, vanilla, strawberry) individually - but is there a way for Excel to know what arithmetic function based off Sheet 2, column A to follow instead of me manually adjusting each row to fit the right formula?

So essentially, some sort of function or VBA method that will tell Excel, "Grab & understand the arithmetic symbol/equation in that row and follow that command" so I don't have to adjust each row to the correct math symbol?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for named ranges? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64 That way you can create named entities that you can reference. Additionally, you could create VBA functions to represent each formula you need.

Comment: If you need to automatically parse the list on sheet1 to create the named ranges for each entry that would require a VBA script but if you can do that part manually then VBA shouldn't be required.

Answer (score 0):

Basically we could use `RegEx` to recognize the 'name' and then get the address of the value of the 'name'. Then we could derive a formula in `Sheet2`.

```
Sub Test()
Set mysheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "\w+"
regEx.Global = True
For i = 1 To mysheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    formula_str = mysheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value

    Set oMatches = regEx.Execute(formula_str)
    For Each oMatch In oMatches
        formula_str = Replace(formula_str, oMatch, getAdd(oMatch))
    Next

    mysheet2.Cells(i, 2) = "=" & formula_str

Next

End Sub

'Function to get the address of 'names'
Function getAdd(keyword)
    Set mysheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    getAdd = ""
    With mysheet1
        For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            If .Cells(i, 1) = keyword Then
                getAdd = mysheet1.Name & "!" & .Cells(i, 2).Address
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

Currently this solution has the limit that all the 'names' must be alphabet format. If you want to use names containing digits and other characters, you should change the `RegEx` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

if your formulas keep sticking to Excel UI formula input rules then you  could give this a try

```
Sub Main()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim strng As String
    Dim element As Variant
    Dim elementValue As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            strng = cell.Value2
            For Each element In Split(Replace(Replace(cell.Value2, "(", ""), ")", ""))
                If GetValue(CStr(element), elementValue) Then strng = Replace(strng, element, elementValue)
            Next
            cell.Offset(, 1).Formula = Replace("=" & strng, " ", "")
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function GetValue(elementName As String, elementValue As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim f As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set f = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Find(what:=elementName, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            elementValue = f.Offset(, 1)
            GetValue = True
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: @S31, any feedback?